# Can assemblies be loaded without using interfaces?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, .net-assembly

I had setup a small plugin system that relied on using interfaces. But I found out that interfaces couldn't be serialized and my entire save system is reliant on serializing files, which will contain these plugins.

So I decided to swap the interface for an abstract class. Which worked fine. But it seems that my current solution requires an interface.

The types for the assembly only show null and Resources. So I'm just guessing that loading assemblies in this way can't be done with abstract classes? Is there a way to do it without using interfaces?

```
public List<EnginePluginBase> GetEnginePlugins(string directory)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
        return null;

    List<EnginePluginBase> plugins = new List<EnginePluginBase>();
    foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles("*.dll"))
    {
        Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName);

        foreach (Type type in GetTypesLoaded(currentAssembly))
        {
            if (type != typeof(EnginePluginBase))
                continue;

            EnginePluginBase plugin = (EnginePluginBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            plugins.Add(plugin);
        }
    }

    return plugins;
}

private Type[] GetTypesLoaded(Assembly assembly)
{
    Type[] types;
    try
    {
        types = assembly.GetTypes();
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        types = e.Types.Where(t => t != null).ToArray();
    }

    return types;
}
```

Comment: you can do it with Abstract class

Comment: We are missing the code of GetTypesLoaded. Anyway, this `if (type != typeof(EnginePluginBase))` seems wrong: You shoudl find (I assume) types that inherit from EnginePluginBase. Try using `IsAssignableFrom`: `if (! typeof(EnginePluginBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))`

Comment: @GianPaolo GetTypesLoaded is just assembly.GetTypes() with a null check. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: You might like to consider if you are solving the right problem - Have you considered sticking with your working interface-based implementation and revising your serialisation approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GetTypesLoaded seems too forgiving with exceptions: 
If there are exception in loading types, you need to understand the reason.
Try to examine the exception you get (`e.LoaderExceptions` is a good candidate)

As I told in comment, modify the check for the type you are looking for:
change

```
if (type != typeof(EnginePluginBase)) 
    continue;
```

to

```
if (! typeof(EnginePluginBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    continue;
```

This should work both with abstract base class (`EnginePluginBase`) or Interface (such `IEnginePlugin`)

Also, it works with types inherited not directly from `EnginePluginBase`  - i.e. a class that inherits from another class that inherits from `EnginePluginBase` (or implements `IEnginePlugin`)

Comment: It turns out I was using a library that hadn't been updated to the abstract class. So it was still trying to use the interface. So that's why it wasn't working. But regardless, my original type check wouldn't have worked. So I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `type !=typeof(EnginePluginBase)` to `type.BaseType !=typeof(EnginePluginBase)` as its a base class also Not sure what is this method `GetTypesLoaded` . 
here is the code what i use and works for me i think should work for you.

```
Assembly asm = null;
asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(strProtocolDll);
 Type[] assemblyTypes = asm.GetTypes();
  foreach (Type module in assemblyTypes)
   {
     if (typeof(ProtocolBase) == module.BaseType)
        {
            return (ProtocolBase)Activator.CreateInstance(module);
        }
    }
```